# (Bridgeland stability conditions) How can I get the heart of a bounded t-structure on $D^b(P^3)$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories

In the article, *Bayer, Arend; Macrì, Emanuele; Toda, Yukinobu*, [**Bridgeland stability conditions on threefolds. I Bogomolov-Gieseker type inequalities**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S1056-3911-2013-00617-7), J. Algebr. Geom. 23, No. 1, 117-163 (2014). [ZBL1306.14005](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1306.14005), I cannot understand something.

Above Lemma 8.2.3, the authors wrote that “by a classical result of Beilinson, on **$D^b(P^3)$** we have a bounded t-structure with heart given by $C\mathrel{:=}\langle O_{P^3}(-1)[3], O_{P^3}[2], O_{P^3}(1)[1],  O_{P^3}(2)\rangle$.”

**Q:** How can I get the heart as above?

Comment: TeX note:  please use $C := \langle a, b, c\rangle$ `$C := \langle a, b, c\rangle$`, not *C* := <$a$, $b$, $c$> `*C* := <$a$, $b$, $c$>`—TeX/MathJax will handle the spacing better that way (and the 'C' and commas are properly placed in math mode).  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: $C$ gives a so-called tilting bundle on $\mathbb{P}^3$, and general theory tells us that $RHom(C, -)$ provides a derived equivalence with the derived category of modules over $End(C)$. Pulling back the standard tilting structure on $D^b(End(C)-mod)$ provides your desired t-structure. Alternatively, you can express this without passage to $D^b(End(C)-mod)$, by knowing that $C$ should be projective in your new heart, e.g. the right wing $D^{\ge 0}$ of the t-structure is complexes $M$ satisfying $Hom(C, M[i]) = 0$ for $i$ negative ...I'm sture material very close to this is in Huybrecht's book.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is Lemma 3.14 of Macri's paper ["Some examples of spaces of stability conditions on derived categories"](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0411613) combined with Beilinson's classic theorem.

There he shows that given an Ext-exceptional collection $\{ E_{1},\dots , E_{n} \} $ on a triangulated category, then $\langle E_{1},\dots, E_{n} \rangle$ is the heart of a bounded t-structure on T.

An Ext-exceptional collection is an exceptional collection such that $Hom^{\leq 0}(E_i,E_j)=0$ for every $i\not= j$. Beilinson's theorem gives a complete exceptonal collection of $D^{b}(\mathbb{P}^{n})$ as $\{ \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{n}} , \dots , \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{n}}(n) \}$ . Any twist also produces such a collection so in particular twisting by -1.

What remains to show is that $\{ \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{3}}(-1)[3],\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{3}}[2],\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{3}}(1)[1],\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{3}}(2) \}$ is Ext-exceptional.

We have $Hom^{-i}(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{3}}(-1)[3],\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{3}}[2])=Hom(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{3}}(-1)[3],\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{n}}[2-i])=0$, similarly $Hom^{-i}(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{3}}(2),\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{3}}(1)[1])=Hom(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{3}}(2),\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{3}}(1)[1-i])=0$, in the first case because the shift wont let the complexes match correctly, and in the second case because the collection is exceptional. The rest of the cases are analogous.

I hope I didnt mess up any grading.

Comment: Thanks AT0 for the answer. I have some more questions.
1. Is the heart determined uniquely or not ?
2. Do you know how to get the heart of bounded t-structure on $D^b(P^1\times P^2)$ ?