# (Bridgeland stability conditions)How to get the heart of a bounded t-structure on $D^b(P^1 \times P^2)$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories, line-bundles

I have already known how to get the heart of a bounded t-structure on $D^b(P^n)$ by Macri`s paper,
https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0411613.

However I cannot purpose analogously on $D^b(P^1 \times P^2)$.

How to get the heart of a bounded t-structure on $D^b(P^1 \times P^2)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are looking for an analogous result of [your previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382331/bridgeland-stability-conditions-how-can-i-get-the-heart-of-a-bounded-t-structu).

In this case I think you could use Corollary 2.7 of Orlov's paper ["PROJECTIVE BUNDLES, MONOIDAL TRANSFORMATIONS, AND DERIVED CATEGORIES OF COHERENT SHEAVES"](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1070/IM1993v041n01ABEH002182)

> If there exists a complete exceptional set in the derived category D^{b}(M) then the derived category D^{b}(E) also posseses a complete exceptional set

Here M is a smooth projective variety, E is a rank r vector bundle over M and $p:\mathbb{P}(E)\to M$  is the associated projective bundle.

If the complete exceptional collection over $D^{b}(M)$ is $\{E_{0},\dots,E_{n}\}$ then the complete exceptional collection over $E$ is given by $\{p^{\ast}E_0\otimes \mathcal{O}_{E}(-r+1),\dots p^{\ast}E_n\otimes \mathcal{O}_{E}(-r+1),\dots, p^{\ast}E_{0},\dots, p^{\ast}E_{n}\}$.

In our particular case $M=\mathbb{P}^{2}$ and $E$ produces the trivial projective bundle $\mathbb{P}^{1}\times \mathbb{P}^{2}$ over $\mathbb{P}^{2}$, for example we can consider E to be the rank 2 vector bundle $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{2}}\oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{2}}$ over $\mathbb{P}^{2}$ (so $\mathbb{P}(E)=\mathbb{P}^{1}\times\mathbb{P}^{2}$ ), the complete exceptional collection over $\mathbb{P}^{2}$ we can take to be $\{ \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{2}},\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{2}}(1),\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{2}}(2) \}$ by Beilinson's result and so by Orlov's result you have a complete exceptional collection on $D^{b}(\mathbb{P}^{1}\times \mathbb{P}^{2})$ given by $\{ p^{\ast}\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{2}} \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{1}\times  \mathbb{P}^{2}}(-1),p^{\ast}\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{2}}(1) \otimes\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{1}\times \mathbb{P}^{2}}(-1),p^{\ast}\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{2}}(2)\otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{1}\times \mathbb{P}^{2} }(-1), p^{\ast}\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{2}} ,p^{\ast}\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{2}}(1) ,p^{\ast}\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{2}}(2)  \}$.

Now it would be good if we could use Macri's result about Ext-exceptional collections. We can simply shift this in an adequate way.

Denote the exceptional collection above as $\{E_{0},\dots,E_{5}\}$, then the collection $\{ E_{0}[5],E_{1}[4],\dots,E_{5}\}$ is Ext-exceptional because $Hom^{-k}(E_{i}[-i+5],E_{j}[-j+5])=Hom(E_{i}[-i+5],E_{j}[-j+5-k])=0$ since $-i+5=-j+5-k$ if and only if $i>j$ and $\{E_{0},\dots, E_{5}\}$ is exceptional.

So using Macri's result we have that $\langle E_0[5],E_{1}[4], \dots, E_{5} \rangle$ is the heart of a bounded t-structure on $D^{b}(\mathbb{P}^{1}\times \mathbb{P}^{2})$

Comment: @AT0You wrote the projection $p:E \to M$. However, in Orlov`s paper, $p:P(E) \to M$ where E is vector bundle of rank r over M. I think it is some different.

Comment: @AT0I have some more questions. I have already known full exceptional collection on $D^b(P^1 \times P^2)$ such that $O(a,b), O(a,b+1),O(a,b+2),O(a+1,b),O(a+1,b+1),O(a+1,b+2)$, 6 objects. $O(a,b):={\pi_1}^*O_{P^1}(a) \otimes {\pi_2}^*O_{P^2}(b)$ where $\pi_1: P^1 \times P^2 \to P^1$ and  $\pi_2: P^1 \times P^2 \to P^2$. Is this exceptional collection is equivalent to your complete exceptional collection?

Comment: @H.S.Kim I apologize, the answer before was wrong and the notation was not perfectly clear. I fixed it so that the projective bundle P(E) matches how its written in Orlov's paper. Also I wrote down Orlov's result wrong and wrote -r-1 when it is -r+1 , so there are indeed 6 elements in the full exceptional colection, the number of elements in such a collection is an invariant of the derived category. I think this should be correct now, sorry for the inconvenience. Im unsure about your second question at the moment, will update later.

Comment: @AT0Thanks for your answer. I have one more question. What is $\mathcal{O}_\mathbb{P^1 \times P^2}(-1)$ ? I cannot understand this notation. I wait your answer for my above question and this question. Thank you.

Comment: @H.S.Kim I added an example of a rank 2 vector bundle over P2 which gives you $P(E)=Proj(Sym(E^{\ast}))=P1 \times P2$. Since $Sym(E^{\ast})$ is a graded $\mathcal{O}_{P^{2}}$ algebra, you can perform the same construction of shifting the grading that you do for P^n for example. Hope this is more clear. As for your second question Im inclined to say yes, they give the same heart, but Im struggling with the calculations at the moment, still.

Comment: Alternatively you can pullback $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{2}}(-1) $ via the projection from $\mathbb{P}^{1}\times \mathbb{P}^{2}$. Im finding it terribly frustrating to find a good resource for this online to reference all of this, but the standard textbooks probably have brief discussions when introducing projective bundles as projectivizations of vector bundles.

Comment: I just realized this answers your second question in the positive, ha, the two full exceptional collections are the same.

Comment: @AT0So, how can I see they are the same?

Comment: @H.S.Kim Sorry, it should've read "Alternatively you can pullback $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{1}}(-1)$ " , notice the change from P^2 to P^1, my bad. This is true because we are dealing with the trivial bundle projective bundle P2xP1. So the sheaves $\mathcal{O}_{P^1 \times P^2} (-1)$ are just what you call $\pi_{1}^{\ast}(\mathcal{O}_{P^{1}}(-1))$ and so my sequence is the one you describe in your comment for a=-1, b=0.

Comment: @AT0Sorry, I have one more question. You write the comment above, "Since $\it{Sym}(E^*)$ is a graded $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}$ algebra, you can perform the same construction of shifting the grading that you do for P^n for example. Hope this is more clear." However, I`m not clear about this. Why $\it{Proj(Sym(E^*))}=\mathbb{P^1 \times P^2}$ ?

Comment: @H.S.Kim Could you say more about what is not convincing to you? Perhaps Im not being as formal as I should, apologies again for the confusion, here where I write Proj in P(E)=Proj(sym(E*)), I mean the relative proj over $\mathbb{P}^{2}$ , locally on an affine open U=Spec(A) of P2, it looks like Proj A[x1,x2] (this one is the regular proj ). The relative proj takes as input a locally free graded qcoherent sheaf over a base scheme S, Sym(E*) is such a sheaf over P2.